# How to get the string in Kotlin to readable format?

Tags: kotlin

I don't know how to get the string in readable format in my app. My code is:

```
    val allergyList = recipeItem.allergies
    allergyList.joinToString()
    var allergyString: String = ""
    for (allergy in allergyList) {
        allergyList[1]
        allergyString += " ${allergy}"
        println(allergy.toString())
    }

    holder.recipeSearchPageAllergies.text = allergyString
```

When I print this I get the allergy string memory space?

Result for each one is something like this:

`Allergy@4e8f238`

How do I 'decode' it into something readable for a human? It should say 'nut allergy'.

Comment: you need to override .toString in your allergy class. (or call another method on it)

Comment: So what I understand is that the normal .toString() method is a pointer to the memory space and when I override the method in my allergy class, I tell it to print the value that memory space contains? Am I understanding this correctly?

Thank you! How can I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: could you please add your definition of `Allergy` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have some options. If you have the control over the `Allergy` source code, 
you could override `toString` method:

```
class Allergy(val name: String) {
    override fun toString(): String = "Allergy[name=${name}]"
}

println(Allergy("flowers"))

// Allergy[name=flowers]
```

also, you can make a data class of it. Data class has sane `toString` by default. It also has a few nice perks, like by default `equals/hashCode` generation, and deconstruction to components, allowing you to use it in destructing:

```
data class Allergy(val name: String)

println(Allergy("peanuts"))

// Allergy(name=peanuts)
```

otherwise, if you can't modify the source of the `Allregy`, you can make up an extension method for that:

```
class Allergy(val name: String)

fun Allergy.readable() = "Allergy[name=${name}]"

println(Allergy("cats").readable())

// Allergy[name=cats]
```

in your case, you could also make an extension method for collections of allergies to have the format you need:

```
fun Collection<Allergy>.readable() = joinToString { "Allergy[name=${it.name}]" }

println(
    listOf(Allergy("cats"), Allergy("peanuts"), Allergy("flowers")).readable()
)

// Allergy[name=cats], Allergy[name=peanuts], Allergy[name=flowers]

// in your case: 
holder.recipeSearchPageAllergies.text = recipeItem.allergies.readable()

// or just 
holder.recipeSearchPageAllergies.text = recipeItem.allergies.joinToString { "Allergy[name=${it.name}]" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simplier:

```kotlin
val allergiesStr = recipeItem.allergies.map { allergy ->
 // your allergy name from  allergy variable
}.joinToString(separator = " ")
```

Comment: `joinToString()` takes an optional `transform` parameter which avoids a separate `map()` call.  IDEA has an code inspection which suggests using that, as it's more efficient as well as more concise.

Comment: I know... Idea is always few steps forward me... that's very annoying, isn't it? The purpose of my code was only showing a different approach that avoids "for loops", variable declaration and unwanted logic  (sum of strings using templates).
Regarding the rest, as you know, there is always space to make it more elegant and concise when you have the basic idea (and IDEA)